# Artificial neural network configuration

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I believe I know the answer to this question already, but I wanted the input from the community. Below is my question.

The following diagram represents an artificial neural network for an associative memory as discussed in this chapter.
What stable configuration would it associate with any initial pattern in which only two neurons that are opposite each
other on the perimeter were excited?

[image]

Answer 1 : If the network is given an initial configuration in which only two opposing units are excited, it will blink – alternating between vertical and horizontal “lines.”

Answer 2: If the network is given an initial configuration in which only two opposing units are excited, the center until will be excited and all the perimeter units will remain inhibited.

Answer 3: Any pattern in which at least two perimeter units are excited and the center unit is inhibited is associated with the pattern in which the perimeter units, as well as the center unit, are excited.

Answer4: Any pattern in which at least two perimeter units are excited and the center unit is inhibited is associated with the pattern in which the perimeter units are excited and the center unit is inhibited.

The answer I choose was answer 4. The reason why I choose answer 4 is because if you look at the diagram the weight of the outer diagram are positive. This may sound trivial, but because the sum of the neurons of the perimeter is positive output( i.e 1)  this would cause opposite perimeter to be excited.

Comment: I upvoted your other question just now, so you can now post pictures. There will be a button you can click when you are creating a question.

Comment: You're welcome. How does this neural net work? I'm used to there being input and output nodes

Comment: You and me both. This is all the question. I'm assuming this a more theory question. If I have the theory right about neural networks and how to calculate a neuron to be excited this should be my answer. When you say how does a neural net work what don't you understand? Maybe I can clarify?